# Python best practice creating variables with dynamic name

Tags: python, xml, variables, dynamic

I want to read from a XML file a variable name and the value to create this variable. After this i also want to read and execute a Python code from the XML file. This Python code will use this variable.

What is the best practise for creating variables with dynamic name?

globals() / locals() / vars()

```
globals()['varName'] = value
```

or dictonary?

```
a['varName'] = value
```

---

### Edit:

Excepted for the savety, is it maybe a good Solution to use exec() to create a variable?

```
exec(varname + " = " + value)
```

Comment: The intro is about xml, the question is about dynamically creating variables, and the rule ["do not ask opinion-based questions"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) is broken. -1

Comment: Use a dict, definitly. That's the only sane option here. And as far as I'm concerned I would NOT execute code coming from an untrusted source.

Answer (score 1):

For sure the dictionary approach would be safer.

Have you thought about using Named Tuples? Here is an example of how to load a JSON (not an XML) into a Named Tuple.

https://gist.github.com/gbinside/9a7154c1de05608811da8da3bf335bfd